# Push notification foreground and background

Tags: java, notifications

I've created a simple  notification and styled it with different colors and general style using a completely new layer created and designed..
Once I trigger the notification though Firebase Messages, when the app is at the foreground, it works perfectly showing the exact styling I need.

But when the app is in the background, it uses it's fugly default style.

Anyway to fix that? Thanks.

The notification java class file code -

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessagingServic";

public MyFirebaseMessagingService() {
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: Message Received! \n " +
        "Title : " + title + "\n" +
            "Message : " + message);

    sendNotification(title, message);

}

@Override
public void onDeletedMessages() {



}

private void sendNotification(String title, String messageBody) {

    final RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_layout);

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.remoteview_notification_short_message, messageBody);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notificationDate, title);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    String channelId = "0";
    Uri defaultSoundUri= Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/notice");
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)

                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.minilogored)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setContent(remoteViews)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setLights(0xf14d39, 1500, 2000)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);


    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

}

Comment: Please show us some code for what you have tried so far.

Comment: @sorifiend I've added the code needed.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the link to know more about Data message and Display message how to handle in onMessageReceived() callback function.

[How to handle notification when app in background in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive